# POST route coming back with error 404, React app with Express server?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a React app with Express Server. I keep getting a few errors, they looks something like this..

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/contactus 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:86
wrap @ bind.js:9
handleSubmit @ Contact.js:20
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:389
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3287
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:3259
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3514
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21871
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:795
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4267
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4189
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21887
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
Contact.js:24 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

**Server.js** Express Server/Back-end

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
var API_KEY = process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY;
var DOMAIN = process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN;
var mailgun = require("mailgun-js")({ apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN });

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// Define API routes here
app.post("/contactus", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  const data = {
    from: req.body.email,
    to: "<__RECEIVER__>",
    subject: "Contact",
    html: `hi`,
  };

  mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      console.log(body);
      res.json({ message: "success" });
    }
  });
});
// Send every other request to the React app
// Define any API routes before this runs
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I went through and checked out the middleware, and thought that might be a possibility.
I then went through and checked out the Front-end/Contact.js to see if it was setup correctly. It seems to work fine, the only issue is getting the POST route server error. I also though something might be wrong with the headers but i'm not getting a CORS policy error. Maybe I overlooked something..

**Contact.js** React App/Front-end

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./Contact.module.css";
import RoomIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Room";
import PhoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Phone";
import EmailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Email";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function Contact() {
  const [sentMessage, setSentMessage] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const data = { name, email, description };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    try {
      axios
        .post("/contactus", data)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles["ContactBackgroundPicture"]}>
        <h1 className={styles["ContactHeader"]}>Contact Us</h1>
      </div>
      <div className={styles["ContactWrapper"]}>
        <div className={styles["Contact"]}>
          <div className={styles["AddressWrapper"]}>
            <div className={styles["ContactUsHeader"]}>
              <RoomIcon style={{ color: "green", marginBottom: "2%" }} />
              <h5>Address</h5>
              <br />
              <hr />
              <p>17102 Sentinel Ln. Lindale Tx. 75771</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles["PhoneWrapper"]}>
            <div className={styles["ContactUsHeader"]}>
              <PhoneIcon style={{ color: "green", marginBottom: "2%" }} />
              <h5>Phone</h5>
              <br />
              <hr />
              <p>903-705-8338</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles["EmailWrapper"]}>
            <div className={styles["ContactUsHeader"]}>
              <EmailIcon style={{ color: "green", marginBottom: "2%" }} />
              <h5>Email</h5>
              <br />
              <hr />
              <p>txjuventusfc@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles["ContactOr"]}>OR</div>
        <div className={styles["ContactSubmitMessage"]}>
          {!sentMessage.length ? null : "Message Successfully Sent!"}
        </div>
        <div className={styles["FormWrapper"]}>
          <h3 className={styles["FormHeader"]}>Message Us</h3>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles["TextFieldWrapper"]}>
            <div className={styles["TopTextField"]}>
              <div className={styles["TopFormField"]}>
                <TextField
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  fullWidth
                  required
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="Enter Your Name"
                  name="name"
                />
              </div>

              <div className={styles["BottomFormField"]}>
                <TextField
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  fullWidth
                  required
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="Enter Your Email Address"
                  name="email"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles["BottomTextField"]}>
              <TextField
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                fullWidth
                required
                id="standard-basic"
                label="Your Message Here..."
                name="description"
              />
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className={styles["SubmitButton"]}
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 1):

`const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;`

You have this in your server file, and your React app is showing that it's using `localhost:3000`.  Try setting PORT to 3000 in your environment, or changing the line to this:

`const PORT = 3000;`

Comment: if I change that then I get this error, `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/graysonmcmurry/Desktop/brianmcmurryjuventus/build/index.html'`

Comment: The good news is that error is being thrown by your express server, so your React application is now connected to it properly.  Is there an index.html file at the path being specified?  It looks to me like your `app.get("*")` route is the one that's throwing that

Comment: I figured out the issue, my first configurations were correct. Thank you for your help!